# How to access a JFrame from anonymous ActionListener for adding a panel in frame?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I want to add a JPanel in a frame if a certain button is clicked and I don't know how to manage that from an anonymous ActionListener. Here is the code:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
   JPanel panel;
   JButton button;
   public MyFrame() {
      button = new JButton("Add panel");
      button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            panel = new JPanel();
            //here I want to add the panel to frame: this.add(panel), but I don't know
            //how to write that. In these case "this" refers to ActionListener, not to
            //frame, so I want to know what to write instead of "this" in order to
            //refer to the frame
         }
      }
      this.add(button);
  }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: instead of `this.add(..)` just use `add(..)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> here I want to add the panel to frame: this.add(panel), but I don't
>   know how to write that. **In these case "this" refers to ActionListener,
>   not to frame, so I want to know what to write instead of "this" in
>   order to refer to the frame**

Instead of `this.add(...)` just use `add(..)` or you can use `MyFrame.this.add(..)`  cause using `this` in anonymous class means that you are referring to `ActionListener` instance.

Actually you may also have to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()`  after you add a component.

Comment: +1, @user2781473 what's happening when you use `this`, it's considering `this` ass the `ActionListener` class, and there is not `add()` method for that class.

Comment: I didn't even notice that in the comments of the code. Basically my comment, just states what in the code comment. I need to pay closer attention next time. It's very late here :)

Comment: When using Swing you should use revalide(), repaint() after adding/removing components.

Comment: @camickr as he is in top container .. using validate in jframe is not the same?

Comment: The revalidate() method was added to the Component class in JDK7. I would guess this method was added for consistency reasons.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers! If I use only `repaint()`, it doesn't work at all. But if I use `revalidate()` and `repaint()`, the panel it's not shown unless I click on it(I mean, the panel appears only if I click where the panel should appear). What am I doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 5):

User generic code in your ActionListener so you don't need to hardcode the class that you are using.

Something like:

```
JButton button = (JButton)event.getSource();
Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForCompnent( button );
window.add(...);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. A very useful custom ActionListener that can be used more than once.

Answer (score 4):

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
   JPanel panel;
   JButton button;
   public MyFrame() {
      button = new JButton("Add panel");
      button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            panel = new JPanel();
            //here I want to add the panel to frame: this.add(panel), but I don't know
            //how to write that. In these case "this" refers to ActionListener, not to
            //frame, so I want to know what to write instead of "this" in order to
            //refer to the frame
            MyFrame.this.add(panel);
         }
      }
      this.add(button);
  }
```

Comment: Upps, @nachokk was quicker.